# an error occurred in Jquery regarding animate();

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a code like

```
setInterval(function(){
    var $first = $('.slider li').first();
    $('.slider').animate({'margin-left' : '-800px'}, 1000, function(){
        $('.slider').append($first).css('margin-left' : '0px');
    });
}, 3000);
```

but Error Message Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list is found and that animate doesn't work at all... can anyone help me with this Error?

Comment: try replace `$('.slider').append($first).css('margin-left' : '0px');` to `$('.slider').append($first).css('margin-left', '0px');`

Comment: What editor are you using? Any good programmer's editor will flag the exact positions on the line with the error on it (the code that @sergeykuznetsov is referring to). For example, the JetBrains IDEs (WebStorm, PyCharm, IntelliJ, etc.) will put a red squiggly next to the colon after `'margin-left'` and another one at the end of the line. You don't need to guess at this stuff, let a good editor/IDE help you. Of course the squigglies may not tell you _exactly_ what the error is, but they will sure help you narrow it down.

Comment: Read how to use .css to set CSS values with jQuery https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp It's easy to get confused when you're thinking about just using CSS style sheets.